# What in heaven's name will actually clear .libPaths in R?

Tags: r, shared-libraries, library-path

Based on a number of answers on the web, I've tried multiple approaches:

```
.libPaths():
[1] "/home/balter/conda/lib/R/library" "/home/balter/R"
> .library=""
> .library.site=c("")
> .libPaths()
[1] "/home/balter/conda/lib/R/library" "/home/balter/R"
> Sys.unsetenv("R_LIBS_SITE");Sys.unsetenv("R_LIBS");Sys.unsetenv("R_LIBS_USER")
> .libPaths()
> .libPaths()
[1] "/home/balter/conda/lib/R/library" "/home/balter/R"
> .libPaths("")
> .libPaths()
[1] "/home/balter/conda/lib/R/library"
> .libPaths("")
> .libPaths()
[1] "/home/balter/conda/lib/R/library"
> .library.site
[1] ""
> assign(".lib.loc", "")
> .libPaths()
[1] "/home/balter/conda/lib/R/library"
```

I would like to be able to set `.libPaths` to empty, or at least *exactly* what I want it to be with no residuals.

Comment: I’m not sure what you’re end result is supposed to be here, but a quick scan of the docs would at least suggest that maybe you’re misspelling a few things here. Capital “L”?

Comment: `.Library` is in the base namespace and cannot be changed; it is set at startup based on R_HOME, and must be defined (else R wouldn't be able to find packages necessary to start up!). You've managed to do all you can do -- remove all other library paths.

Comment: @MartinMorgan Thanks for explaining that! Gosh, there are quite a few others asking very similar questions, and I have not seen a clear explanation of the issue before.